# How do I power this 400V motor from 230V?

Tags: three-phase, induction-motor

[image]

I just bought a lathe with a motor that used to be connected to 3 phase 400V. I am trying to power it using single phase 230V domestic mains. I understand that I can use a VFD to provide the extra phases, but I am not sure if I need to buy a step up transformer as well. I read somewhere that some motors can be configured to run on 2 different voltages, but I'm not sure if mine supports this as I just read an answer to a different question which suggested that my motor is dual speed.

Would it be a problem if I ran it with just a VFD and no transformer?

I have also included a picture of the wiring diagrams in the lid of the junction box.

[image]

Comment: You need to find a proper data sheet for the motor.

Comment: "*Would it be a problem if I ran it with just a VFD and no transformer?*" If would be considerably weaker. About 1/4.

Comment: Even if you find a  step-up transformer, VFDs for 400V or 380VAC may require 3-phase input power so take care before making a purchase. The HV power rail filter capacitor (and individual rectifier diodes) can be considerably smaller for 3-phase input, so it's not just a matter of disabling phase loss protection as some seem to believe.

Comment: Many comments [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=operate+3+phase+motor+on+single+phase&oq=operate+3+phase+motor+on+single+phase&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIICAEQABgWGB4yCAgCEAAYFhgeMggIAxAAGBYYHjIICAQQABgWGB4yCAgFEAAYFhgeMggIBhAAGBYYHjIICAcQABgWGB4yCAgIEAAYFhgeMggICRAAGBYYHtIBCjEzMDg0ajBqMTWoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Google search. || Some better than others. || [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOzmlJfz2DA) is a very simple method often used for small motors. May or may not suit your power level.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 3-phase motor. It will not start to rotate with a single phase outlet. Even if you start it by hand, it will not produce any torque.

Single phase motors with a capacitor have a special winding to produce some rotating field. You cannot just add a capacitor to a regular 3-phase motor and expect it to work.

---

Update:

According to e.g. [this](https://www.emotorsdirect.ca/knowledge-center/article/why-singlephase-induction-motors-need-capacitors) reliably sounding source, the single-phase induction motor has a second winding at 90 degrees from the main winding, which creates a usable rotating magnetic field for the rotor to spin. It needs TWO capacitors: a large one for starting the motor, and a smaller afterwards.

This means that you can experiment with capacitors on your three-phase motor, but it will work worse than a regular single-phase motor, which already is inferior to a three-phase motor. Good Luck!

Comment: actually you can just add a capacitor, you won't get full power  but it will spin.